# Implement OnClickListener when using sliding tabs & viewpageradaptor in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have implemented a sign-in activity and a register activity in my android app.  They both work fine and connect to the database and read/write to it.

My classes are Login.java and Register.java for my login and register activities and are currently declared as:

```
 public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
My Code Here
    }
    public class Register extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
      My Code here
    }
```

Now, my next stage is to integrate them into a sliding tab material design layout.

To create the material design sliding tab layout I am implementing the following classes and making use of a layout tab_bar.xml.  This layout works quite well when I implement some basic content for each tab...example textview Tab1 and Tab2 on each respective tab.

```
SlidingTabLayout.java
SlidingTabStrip.java
ViewPagerAdapter.java
```

My ViewpagerAdapter.java class is declared as

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
}

The problem is that I am unsure as to how I should integrate my working login.java and register.java classes with the above three classes.

I have done many searches for how to implement `View On Click Listener` with sliding tabs etc and come up empty.  I have found many resources for how to create sliding tabs, but I specifically want to find one on how to implement edit texts, buttons etc into a sliding tab layout.

Do you have or can you provide links to tutorials/examples of this layout.

Comment: Each Tab in your PagerSlidingTabStrip is a fragment and fragments can have their own layouts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend you edit your post and state a clear question on your issue. Asking for a tutorial/example is out of scope. I think you can rephrase your question to avoid having your post closed as off-topic.